# How do I find org-mode files with completion in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, org-mode, icicles, emacs-helm

I have a growing set of org files stored in `org-directory`. How can I navigate between them, preferably with interactive filtering and completion?

I thought there was a way to get org-mode to produce a list of known org files for quick navigation, but I can't seem to find it. If org-mode does not have this feature, how can I make a simple command that launches something like helm or icicles to find them?

Comment: EmacsWiki has some examples using `ido` -- e.g., **Helper Function to Select Based on Mode**:  http://emacswiki.org/emacs/InteractivelyDoThings  There are also buffer-list menus already built-in -- e.g., imenu, list-buffers, speedbar (buffers view), etc. -- sorting is possible by major-mode; and, it is also possible to set up filters to display only buffers of interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is not very clear to me. But if your Org-mode files all have a certain file-name pattern (e.g. `*.org`) and all are in the same directory (`org-directory`) then you can use several methods Emacs method to access them:

1. `C-x C-f *.org RETURN` in `org-directory` opens them all (the buffers are visiting them but only the last one is shown).
2. `C-x C-f *.org TAB` in `org-directory`, to show them using completion, then pick whichever one you want (or pick more than one, using a glob pattern, as in #1).
3. The same as #2, using Icicles or Helm.  In Icicles, at least, you can also match using regexps and in other ways.
4. Open Dired for just those files: `C-x d *.org`.

There are really any number of ways to do what you've described. But I'm guessing that you have not really described your request/problem/question well enough, and when you do you will get a narrower set of answers.

---

**UPDATE after your comments:**

Here's one way: Open Dired on all of your Org files in and under `org-directory`.

```
(defun foo ()
  "Open Dired for (only) the Org files in and under `org-directory`."
  (interactive)
  (cd org-directory)
  (dired "*.org" "-lRF"))
```

Test it with `M-x foo`.  Put this in your init file:

```
(foo)
```

And here's another way: `M-x bar` or bind `bar` to a key.

```
(defun bar ()
  "Open an Org file in or under `org-directory`."
  (interactive)
  (let ((default-directory         org-directory)
        (icicle-file-match-regexp  ".*\\.org"))
    (icicle-locate-file-of-content)))
```

Comment: Yes, all of my org files match `*.org` and are in somewhere under `org-directory` (perhaps a subdir). I am looking for a single command that can set up the search similar to how you are suggesting, but without having to navigate to the directory and type in the regex each time.

Comment: That's useful for opening a list of the org files, but not for quickly jumping to one of them. How would you do the same thing for initializing one of the find-file options you mention in #2 and #3?

Answer (score 1):

I have a package that does just that: [plain-org-wiki](https://github.com/abo-abo/plain-org-wiki).
It's nothing too elaborate: I just dump all of my 45 org files into a single directory and get completion for them.

Comment: This looks pretty close to what I was asking for. Do you have any documentation or tips on how to set it up and use it? A readme file on your repo would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

How about **org-iswitchb**, which is provided by org already?

S*witch between Org buffers.
With one prefix argument, restrict available buffers to files.
With two prefix arguments, restrict available buffers to agenda files*.

Add this to your startup file after org is loaded:
`(global-set-key "\C-cb" 'org-iswitchb)`

Answer (score 0):

My favorite solution to this is `helm-mode` which is activated with the `helm` package from MELPA. Here's a demo:

[image: Helm Mode Completion]

It really makes for a great environment for searching ones files quickly. In addition, one can enable fuzzy completion! Here's a minimal configuration (after installing the `helm` package):

```
(require 'helm-config)
(helm-mode 1)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-f") 'helm-find-files)
```

You can also run `grep` on the files if you'd like to search their content. Take a look at [this amazing guide](http://tuhdo.github.io/helm-intro.html) if you'd like to learn more.

Comment: I agree that helm is cool for interactively narrowing files, but I was hoping to learn how to set up a search for only org files. It seems possible to do with helm, but I don't know how.